# float em algum elemento, e a div não acompanha o conteúdo

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando flutuar um elemento para a direita, e este elemento está dentro de uma `div` sem tamanho definido. O problema é que quando o flutuo o elemento `p` a `div` não acompanha o conteúdo.

Segue o código HTML:

```
<div id="divPrincipal">
   <p>Conteúdo dentro da div</p>
</div>
```

E o CSS:

```
#divPrincipal{
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#divPrincipal p{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: right;
}
```

Como resolver isto?

Comment: Testei o position, e apliquei nele um left de 1000px. O conteúdo saiu fora da div. Isso porque o elemento p está sendo tratado como um bloco, eu posso defini-lo com um display: table. Seria uma solução.
E sobre o width: 100%, não resolveu a situação não.

Comment: Afinal, você está querendo alinhar a `div` a direita ou os elementos da `div`, ou mesmo ambos?

Comment: O elemento!

Quando disse que a div não acompanha o conteúdo, é poque a div tem seu height como se fosse no tamanho 0px;

Comment: Kazzkiq já respondeu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa limpar o `float` para o elemento pai assumir o tamanho dos seus filhos com `float`. Existem várias maneiras de fazer isto, mas a mais moderna atualmente seria usando algo como [esta solução](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/):

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Onde esta classe CSS seria adicionada ao seu elemento pai, sendo que o HTML ficaria assim:

```
<div id="divPrincipal" class="cf">
   <p>Conteúdo dentro da div</p>
</div>
```

Exemplo: [**`FIDDLE`**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kazzkiq/ae0L0x3d/)